# Add column concatenated from other columns with different types

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've tried this:

`ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD ObjectID AS ("float type column" + "nvarchar(255) type column")`

But I get `Error converting data type nvarchar to float` and checking the new `ObjectID` column its tpye is indeed `(float, null)`.

I would like to make some kind of a computed column with an nvarchar type, which is always the concatenation of certain other columns in the table. Specifying the type of this new column in this alteration command also throws an error.

How should I do this? I've been thinking about creating the column with the type first, then binding the values in the second step, but I'm curious if I could do it in one elegant step.

Comment: The error is telling you the problem here. You need to explicitly convert your `float` column.

Comment: perhaps concat(FloatCol,nvarcharCol)   .... null values will be treated as empty strings

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Yes, that's working, thank you!

Comment: @MattSom Happy to help